# Bash: Define a path that is above absolute path

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I'm running a script in a directory:

```
a/b/c/d/script.bash
```

I need to create an environment variable, projroot, such that

```
  script=$(readlink -f $0) # Absolute path to this script.
  export projroot=$(dirname $(dirname $script)) #This points to the absolute path
```

How do I define `projroot`, so that `projroot` points to `a/b` instead of `a/b/c` ?

Comment: I can just do `$(dirname$(dirname $(dirname $script))) `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `dirname` as well as you can use [bash parameter-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `realpath`.

**Using realpath:**

```bash
script=$(readlink -f "$0")
export projroot=$(realpath -mL "${script}/../../..")
```

**Using bash parameter expansion:**

```bash
script=$(readlink -f "$0")
export projroot="${script%/*/*/*}"
```